# Passing data and variables from service to controller in AngularJS and PouchDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, pouchdb

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
angular.module('msfLogger', ['offClick', 'ngBootstrap', 'ngSanitize','ngCsv', 'angularFileUpload', 'pouchdb'])

.controller('LoggerCtrl',['$scope', 'dataService', 'pouchDB', function($scope, dataService, pouchDB){


var db = pouchDB('FleetDB');

$scope.addTodo = function() {
    var movement = {
        _id: moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss"),
        type: 'move',
        duration:''
    };
    db.put(movement, function(err, res) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    });
}

$scope.recordlist = dataService.get();
console.log($scope.recordlist);
```

The first function works OK and saves data into the DB.

But then, I try to retrieve this data using a service: `dataService.get();`

The service looks like this:

```
angular.module('msfLogger').service('dataService', extractRecords);

function extractRecords() {

    var data = db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true})
    return {
        get: data;
    }
};
```

I'm getting a `db is not defined` error.

How can I make db available in the service and send the data back to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you declare your PouchDB database in the controller, so that variable is not exposed in the service and that's why `db is not defined`.

The way I approach this in Angular, is to create a Service or Factory to manage the PouchDB, because both are singletons, then you can inject that service into your `dataService`, or use it in any other service that manage the DB.

```
angular.module('msfLogger').service('pouchService', PouchService);

function PouchService() {
  var self = this;
  self.db= new PouchDB('FleetDB');
}
```

After being injected instead of doing just this:

```
var data = db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true});
```

Dot that:

```
var db = pouchService.db;
var data = db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true});
```

Comment: Victor that worked like a charm! I have a doubt though! db.allDocs is returning a promise, and deep inside the promise there's the array of objects I query for. How to I turn this promise into a simple array with the objects?

Comment: @EricMitjans you are welcome, yes for sure it's a promise, PouchDB is asynchronous and return a callback or a promise, so you should use it as `db.allDocs({options}).then(function (data) { //use your data }).catch(function (err) { //always catch it });`

Answer (score 1):

Inject your `pouchDb` service into your service, like what you did in your controller.

```
angular.module('msfLogger').service('dataService', ['pouchDB',function(pouchDB){

    //get an instance of your db
    var db = pouchDB('FleetDB');
    var data = db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true})
        return {
            get: data;
    }
}]);
```